# Error activating service - Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, ninject, c#-3.0

I am getting the following error whenever I try to inject one of my service's dependency into the MVC controller:

Error activating IFeedService No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
Activation path:

2) Injection of dependency IFeedService into parameter svc of constructor of type FeedController

1) Request for FeedController

**Suggestions:**

1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IFeedService.

2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel.

3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.

4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name.

5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.

======================================================================

Here's how my code looks like:

### ObjectFactory.cs

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    // Contexts
    kernel.Bind<IEntityObjectContext>().To<Entities>();
    kernel.Bind<IAzureObjectContext>().To<AzureTableObjectContext>();

    // Repositories
    kernel.Bind<IEFRepository>().To<EFRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IAzureRepository>().To<AzureRepository>();

    // Services
    kernel.Bind<IFeedService>().To<FeedService>();
}
```

### IEFRepository.cs

```
public interface IEFRepository : IDisposable
{
    void SetContext(IEntityObjectContext context);
    IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>() where T : class;
}
```

### EFRepository.cs

```
public class EFRepository : IEFRepository
{
    internal IEntityObjectContext context;
    private Dictionary<Type, object> objectSets;

    public EFRepository(IEntityObjectContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        objectSets = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    }

    public void SetContext(IEntityObjectContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

### IFeedService.cs

```
public interface IFeedService : IDisposable
{
    IQueryable<FeedItem> GetPosts();
}
```

### FeedService.cs

```
public class FeedService : IFeedService
{
    private IEntityObjectContext _context;
    private readonly IEFRepository _repo;

    public FeedService(IEntityObjectContext context,
            IEFRepository repo)
    {
        _context = context;
        _repo = repo;
        _repo.SetContext(_context);
    }

    public IQueryable<FeedItem> GetPosts()
    {
        using (_repo)
       {
           return _repo.GetAll<FeedItem>().Take(10);
       }
    }
}
```

### FeedController.cs

```
public class FeedController : Controller
{
    private readonly IFeedService _svc;

    public FeedController(IFeedService svc)
    {
        _svc = svc;
    }
}
```

As you can see, there are some nested dependency there in action. Not sure though, what needs to be added/removed for this bit to work.

Note: The error is thrown whenever I request the Feed/FetchFeed path. I also tried to comment out the FeedService's constructor portion to see if the nested dependencies are creating any problem, but again same error was thrown.

**EDIT 1:**

Rest of the code for the ObjectFactory.cs

```
class ObjectFactory
{
    static ObjectFactory()
    {
        RegisterServices(kernel);
    }
    static IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
    public static T GetInstance<T>()
    {
        return kernel.Get<T>();
    }
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I even tried to write a fairly basic service, but still the same error. Here's what I tried with:

```
public interface ITest
{
    void CheckItOut();
}

public class Test : ITest
{
    public void CheckItOut()
    {
    }
}
```

### ObjectFactory.cs

```
kernel.Bind<ITest>().To<Test>();
```

Comment: Please show us the composition root code where you make the initialisation of ninject.

Comment: @kayess: I have added the rest of the code in the end. Thank you!

Comment: Great! However I still miss the code part where you use the `ObjectFactory`.

Comment: Best guess is that you have registered the container with MVC incorrectly. Are you using `IControllerFactory` or `IDependencyResolver`? Please show the code. Also note that making the kernel static leads to the dreaded [service locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/), and may result in lifetime management issues as well.

Comment: Sure, inside the same project where ObjectFactory is placed, it is used like:

`IAzureRepository repo = new AzureRepository(ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IAzureObjectContext>())`

However, inside my web project it looks like:

`IAzureRepository repo = new AzureRepository(ApplicationRequest.Instance.AzureContext)`, where `AzureContext` is `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IAzureObjectContext>()`
I hope it helps. Thank you! :)

Comment: @Gurdeep please [edit] additional informations/code to your question to make the context of question complete.